# How can I get the index number of every element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery sortable to sort some elements but now I want to be able to order them and save the order to the database.

So I figured the best way to do this is get the index of the element.

This is my html (it's dynamic so there can be infinite categories and questions):

```
<form id="lijstform">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <label class="lijstnaamtitle">Lijst naam</label>
            <input class="form-control name_list catinput lijsttitle" type="text" name="lijsttitle">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dynamic_field" class="ui-sortable">
        <div class="row sortwrap ui-sortable-handle" id="1">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list catinput">
                <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>
                <div class="questionlist questionwrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
                            <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row sortwrap ui-sortable-handle" id="2">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="2. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list catinput"> <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>
                <div class="questionlist questionwrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
                            <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput"> </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="addcategory" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove removebutton">X</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row sortwrap" id="3">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="3. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list catinput"> <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>
                <div class="questionlist questionwrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
                            <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput"> </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="addcategory" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove removebutton">X</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row sortwrap" id="4">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="4. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list catinput"> <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>
                <div class="questionlist questionwrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
                            <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput"> </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="addcategory" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove removebutton">X</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I already have code which adds a number to the placeholder of the input fields.

```
function updatePlaceholders() {
  $('#input-field-id').val($('#input-field-id').val() + 'more text');
  // Sortable code
  let df = $('#dynamic_field');
  df.find('input[name^=cat]').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("placeholder", i + 1 + ". Voeg een categorie toe");
  });
  df.find('.sortwrap').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("id", i + 1);
  });
  df.find('.catinput').each(function(i) {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $(this).val(i + 1 + '.' + ' '+index);
  });
  df.find('.questionlist').each(function() {
    $(this).find('input[name^=qu]').each(function(i) {
      $(this).attr("placeholder", i + 1 + ". Voeg een vraag toe");
    });
  });
}
```

Every add or delete I call the function again to update the numbers:

```
$('#dynamic_field').on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').remove();
  updatePlaceholders();
});
$('#addcategory').on('click', function() {
let t = $(template)
  $('#dynamic_field').append(t);
  updatePlaceholders();
});
```

This is what I tried to get the indexes:

```
df.find('.catinput').each(function(i) {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $(this).val(i + 1 + '.' + ' '+index);
      });
```

But this shows all indexes as being 0, even after adding new input fields. How can I get it to work?

Comment: why not use the `i` ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/index/), it says:

*If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object **relative to its sibling elements**.*

Each of your `catinput` classes are in a different div so **they are not siblings**. That's why `.index()` is returning `0` for each.

If you want the index of that element within your collection, why don't you just use the `i` parameter that you have already defined? Since the first parameter of the `.each()` callback is the index of that element ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/)).

i.e.

```
df.find('.catinput').each(function(i) {
  var index = i;
  //rest of logic
});
```

Comment: I can do that but when adding a new inputfield the sort order is reset and show everything in ascending order instead of the order that I sorted it in before adding a new field.